# get images from json

Tags: android, json, dictionary, cordova, marker

i I have a **json** url like such...

```
{"Status":
    { "Itemlist":[ 
        { 
            "id" : "2", 
            "Name" : "test", 
            "Price" : "10", 
            "image" :"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg" 
        } , 
        { 
            "id" : "4", 
            "Name" : "Burger", 
            "Price" : "20", 
            "image" :"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.jpeg" 
        } , 
        { 
            "id" : "6", 
            "Name" : "a", 
            "Price" : "1", 
            "image" :"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg" 
        } 
    ]}
}
```

I want to  get the image from json url and display it into a list using **javascript** for **phonegap android** applications. 
pls provide me a link

Comment: Could you format that snippet better?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do this from JavaScript here is some basic code to get you started. Where I'm doing a console.log you will want to create your HTML and insert it into the DOM where you want it displayed.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://my.server.com/data.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var list = data.Status.ItemList;
            for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
                console.log("Image url = " + list.image);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
```

Comment: thank u for your code.but i am not able to retreive the images ,it just shows as undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject("JsonResponse");
JSONObject statusObject = mainObject.getJsonObject("Status");
JSONArray dataArray = statusObject.getJsonObject("Itemlist");

JSONObject subObj = null;

for(int i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
{
   subObj = dataArray.getJsonObject(i);
   String strImageURLValue = subObj.getString("image");

}
```

Comment: pls help me to do with javascript?

Comment: @user969275 dear i have already provided a startup for you, don't you think to try and go ahead by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while coding a similar application, you can either use a lazy loader or look at base 64 encoding and decoding.. then implement threading
http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview

http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/implementing-a-lazy-loading-android-gallery-with-mirah/

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed your first error: when passing the url of the image make sure you pass the complete url not zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg, make it http://10.0.2.2/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.jpg, where 10.0.2.2  is the IP of localhost, then employ a lazy loader to render your images preferably into a listview.
 This website might shed light into what you are looking for http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/android-full-app-part-6-customized-list.html

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed the data and also **retrieved the image** using the following code:

```
$.getJSON("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?id=2",

  function(data) {

   $.each(data.Status.Itemlist, function(i,item){


  //$("<img/>").attr("src", item.image).appendTo("#images");
  $('#images ul').append("<li>'<span>"+item.Name+"</span>'<img src='"+item.image+"'
</li>");

   //$('#images ul').append("<li>'"+item.Name+"'</li>");
   //alert(i);
   // alert(item);
   //if(i==4)return false;
   });
});
```